# RollingRandomAccessFile contains an invalid element or attribute JsonTemplateLayout

Tags: java, log4j2

i've a configuration in my log4j2.xml as below -

```
<JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:log4j2JSONLayout.json"/>
```

Throws following error during initialization -

main ERROR RollingRandomAccessFile contains an invalid element or attribute "JsonTemplateLayout"

dependencies added are:

slf4j-api - 1.7.32

jcl-over-slf4j - 1.7.32

log4j-api - 2.17.1

log4j-core - 2.17.1

log4j-layout-template-json - 2.17.1

log4j-slf4j-impl - 2.17.1

Comment: Issue resolved as per - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3321